# Why can't I get my javascript to hide box unless ticked in Sharepoint with Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, knockout.js

It works further down the page by itself, but when I put it in a div in a table it won't work.
The checkbox when ticked will show a date picker, but the checkbox does not show up unless an option from a dropdown is
My code:

javascript:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (checked) {
               $('.other').show();             
            } else {
                $('.other').hide();
            }
        });        
    });
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });


    </script>
```

ASP page:

```
    <td  data-bind="visible: checkBool" style="width: 278px">


                            <input type="checkbox" id="endDateCheck"/> 
                            Tick this box if there is an end date for the 
                            permissions. 
                <div class='other' name='other' title='other' style='display:none;'>  
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
</div>                  
                    </td>
```

Currently, the div called "other" is always hidden regardless of whether  you tick the checkbox or not.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the issue ? Your question is not clear as to what is the issue. Also I think we're missing something here `but the checkbox does not show up unless an option from a dropdown is`. Can u add that as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery or knockout for the solution? If you are using knockout you must first read [here](http://knockoutjs.com) and then
see [in this documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) about knockout checked binding and you will find your answer. Regards